# AngularJS - using $mdMedia to return current media query size

Tags: javascript, angularjs, media-queries

In Angular JS Material I can use the following example to see if 'xs' media query returns true or false, then I can set the variable *'objectSize'* to either 100 if true or 200 if false:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($mdMedia, $scope) {
  $scope.$watch(function () { return $mdMedia('xs'); }, function (size) {
       console.log($scope.objectSize = size ? '100' : '200');
   });
});
```

But how can  I set *'objectSize'* to 100, 200, 300 or 400 depending on the screen sizes 'xs', 'sm', 'md' or 'lg' respectively.

Comment: Create a directive that receives the size of `$mdMedia` how to param and applies a custom size to that object on the view

Comment: Any chance you could provide an example?

Comment: You can use Switch case and based on size available you can change your scenario

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a lot of code, basically the above repeated for each case. Maybe there's a better way but this is how I ended up doing it:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($mdMedia, $scope) {
    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return $mdMedia('xs');
    }, function (xs) {
        if (xs) {
            $scope.imgSize = 140;
        }
    });
    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return $mdMedia('sm');
    }, function (sm) {
        if (sm) {
            $scope.imgSize = 180;
        }
    });
    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return $mdMedia('md');
    }, function (md) {
        if (md) {
            $scope.imgSize = 240;
        }
    });
    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return $mdMedia('lg');
    }, function (lg) {
        if (lg) {
            $scope.imgSize = 300;
        }
    });
});
```